# Teradata - The arguments of the CAST function must be of the same character data type - what does it mean?

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

Can you help me with with TD error?

I just do `cast(array_type as varchar(200)) as col1` and it works but when I use this col1 in the comparison to other column, I get:

> The arguments of the CAST function must be of the same character data type

What is going on?

Comment: Can you share the comparison that you doing along with type of the other column? Share an equivalent sample if sharing exact query is not possible.

Comment: @xenodevil: and it works on different environment.. but on that particular it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Check [this reference](https://docs.teradata.com/r/GVKfXcemJFkTJh_89R34UQ/Do8lM%7EOfPwXC8ikhrszyWg) from Teradata Documentation. It appears that you are casting a character type column with a defined character set to character column with a different character set. To rephrase, you are casting a character to a character, only the charactersets are changing rather than data type, but this is not the intended usage for `CAST` operation.

In order to change character sets, you will need to use `TRANSLATE` rather than `CAST`. Remember that output of `TRANSLATE` can give errors for non-convertible characters, so you may want to play with its arguments to ignore such errors. Check [this Teradata Documentation reference](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/_DNQFbXo2ggrk5%7EHzAoUCA) for `TRANSLATE`.

Remember to check the `WITH ERROR` argument available with `TRANSLATE` if you get issues with non-convertible characters. Depending on your use case, you can then either replace the placeholder character with empty string or take some other action on rows containing the placeholders.